# Correct way to cast to and from push notification dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I want to cast userInfo["aps"] to a dictionary in `application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification`. The current code I have is:

```
HTTPManager.sharedInstance.pushPayload = userInfo["aps"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>.
```

The pushPayload is defined as: `var pushPayload: AnyObject?`

Now I try to unwrap this payload with:

```
if let message = HTTPManager.sharedInstance.pushPayload?["alert"] as? String {
            print("WE HAVE A PAYLOAD AND THE MESSAGE IS: \(message)")

        } else {
            print("Nothing in the payload")
        }
```

I always get nil when I try to unwrap it, even though the payload does contain objects (I am checking using a print statement). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two steps. Make sure that `pushPayload` is of correct type first and then retrieve the value. Try this:

```
if let dict = HTTPManager.sharedInstance.pushPayload as? [String:AnyObject], let message = dict["alert"] {
    print("WE HAVE A PAYLOAD AND THE MESSAGE IS: \(message)")
} else {
    print("Nothing in the payload")
}
```

Also, I don't think there is a need for `as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` in this case.